# Pig ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error (wrong name MY_CLASS_NAME)

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I have an error when trying to Define my UDF in Pig
this is my pig script:

```
REGISTER 'hdfs://localhost:54310/folder/myudf.jar';
DEFINE MYUD myudf.REDECODE();
```

when i execute the second line i get this error message

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal 
error. myudf/REDECODE (wrong name: REDECODE)
```

My udf function :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

import org.apache.pig.PigWarning;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class REDECODE extends EvalFunc<String> {

...

}
```

Please if you can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Is REDECODE class inside package myudf ? I dont see the package declaration statement in UDF class.

Comment: I don't use package in my class

Comment: In that case you have to modify the DEFINE statement as  : DEFINE MYUD REDECODE();  I dont feel the need of this DEFINE statement you can directly use REDECODE()

Comment: Thank you, i removed the DEFINE and i used the redecode directly as you said

Comment: Did it resolve the issue ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works now

Comment: It might be a good idea to accept Murali Rao's answer so this question appears as "answered" in search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Badr comments, REDECODE class is defined in default package either we can use the REDECODE directly in the script or if we need an simple alias for REDECODE then we can use DEFINE and define an alias and use the alias going forward.